# Showing a justification for a statement?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am wondering if my justification are correct.

Assume A,B,and C are positive integers.

**Proposition:**

If A and B are both positive and A divides B, then $A\le B$

**Explanation**

$B=A(K)$  K is an integer.

$B-AK=0$

$AK$ must equal B

If $K=1$ then $A=B$

if $k>1$ then $A<B$

End

**Proposition 2**

A divides A

**Explanation**

$A=K(1)$  K is integer

$A-B=0$

$B=A$

A divides A

Comment: I'd write the second like this: 
$A=A(1)$, hence A divides A (A divides B if $B=AK$ K integer), no need to insert a B in the second explanation

Comment: These are too obvious to be discussed.

Comment: fair enough to say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first proof is just fine. You could also note that given $A = kB$ for some integer $k$, $k\gt 0$, otherwise $B$ would not be positive, which contradicts the hypothesis. Then $\frac Bk = A$, and finish with what you conclude.

For the second, note that we can write $ A=A(1),$, which, by definition, means $A\mid A$, since $1 \in \mathbb Z$.